# Does Nginx respect maxage from upstream server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, http-headers

I see the [`proxy_cache_valid`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_valid) directive, but that confuses me.

In HTTP, doesn't the upstream server specify this with `Cache-Control` and `maxage`?

How do I get Nginx's cache to use `maxage` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly explained in the documentation of `proxy_cache_valid` directive.

> **Parameters of caching can also be set directly in the response header**. **This has higher priority than setting of caching time using the directive**. The **“X-Accel-Expires” header field sets caching time of a response in seconds**. The zero value disables caching for a response. If the value starts with the @ prefix, it sets an absolute time in seconds since Epoch, up to which the response may be cached. **If the header does not include the “X-Accel-Expires” field, parameters of caching may be set in the header fields “Expires” or “Cache-Control”**. If the header includes the “Set-Cookie” field, such a response will not be cached. Processing of one or more of these response header fields can be disabled using the proxy_ignore_headers directive.